# How to interactively build a setup.py file for py2exe by passing in a string of code?

Tags: python, string, metaprogramming

I know this probably covers a lot of different territory, and I've managed to get most of it working except one tiny issue..

Let's say I have a function called make_setup that looks like this:

```
def make_setup(_file_, codestring = None):
    if codestring == None:
        #codestring will be a list passed in
        codestring = ["from distutils.core import setup",
                      "import py2exe",
                      "setup(console=["+_file_+"])"]
    else:
        codestring = codestring

    with open('setup.py', 'w+') as f:

        for line in codestring:
            f.write(line+'\n')

    f.close()
```

then I have another function called build_exe that I will run to actually make my executable. It looks like this:
from subprocess import Popen
import os

```
#build exe
def build_exe(codestring = None):
    if codestring == None:
        codestring = ["python setup.py py2exe"]
    else:
        codetring = codestring

    #write a batch file?
    with open('exe_bat.bat', 'w+') as f:

        for line in codestring:
            f.write(line+'\n')

    f.close()
    #run the batch file
    p = Popen("exe_bat.bat", cwd=os.getcwd())
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Basically, the idea is that I can pass a .py file into my make_setup function so that it correctly references this file in the written setup.py file. Let's pretend I have a file called my_python_code.py that contains everything I need to create my .exe. The contents of this file don't really matter for this example.

When I run my make_setup function by passing in my file:

```
_file_ = r'my_python_code.py'
make_setup(_file_)
```

It creates a setup.py file with the following lines of code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=[my_python_code.py])
```

Notice that the my_python_code.py bit isn't a string.. **Here lies the main issue I could use some help with:**

*How can I pass my filename into my make_setup function so that it correctly creates my setup.py file as:*

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['my_python_code.py'])
```

Thanks for any help!

PS: And just to make it easier to get straight to the point, I know the problem lies is my make_setup function, specifically the last line of this:

```
codestring = ["from distutils.core import setup",
                      "import py2exe",
                      "setup(console=["+_file_+"])"]
```

I have tried `str(_file_)`, and using double quotes"", etc. to no avail. perhaps using the inspect module to get the actual reference .py file and appending to my codestring is an option? I'll keep trying stuff and post when I find a solution.

UPDATE:
Here's what I ended up with:

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO 
except:
    from StringIO import StringIO  

from subprocess import Popen
import os

#make setup.py
def make_setup(_file_, codestring = None):

    def f(_file_): return '\'{0}\''.format(_file_)

    if codestring == None:
        codestring = ["from distutils.core import setup",
             "import py2exe",
             "setup(console=["+f(_file_)+"])"]
    else:
        codestring = codestring

    #this displayes the code 
    output = StringIO()
    for line in codestring:
        #no returns in lines
        output.write(line+'\n')
    print output.getvalue()
    output.close()

    user_response = raw_input("is this correct? y/n")

    if user_response != "y":
        print "try again"
    else:
        with open("setup.py", "w+") as f:
            for line in codestring:
                f.write(line+'\n')
        f.close()

#build exe
def build_exe(codestring = None):
    if codestring == None:
        codestring = ["python setup.py py2exe"]
    else:
        codetring = codestring

    #this displayes the code 
    output = StringIO()
    for line in codestring:
        #no returns in lines
        output.write(line+'\n')
    print output.getvalue()
    output.close()

    user_response = raw_input("is this correct? y/n")

    if user_response != "y":
        print "try again"
    else:        
        #write a batch file?
        with open('exe_bat.bat', 'w+') as f:

            for line in codestring:
                f.write(line+'\n')

        f.close()

    user_response = raw_input("run the batch file? y/n")
    if user_response == 'y':
        #run the batch file
        p = Popen("exe_bat.bat", cwd=os.getcwd())
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate() 
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want quotes in the string you have to put them there. Python can't guess what you want.

```
value = "a nice string"
statement = "my_string = \"{}\"".format(value)
print(statement)
```

Output:

```
my_string = "a nice string"
```

Comment: thank you, I forgot to revisit this after solving it for myself. I'll post my working code as an example now.